# Require.js - Get cross origin error on !text defines when loaded directly in browser

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

When I try to open my single page app without it being hosted, in other words, I open the index.html directly in my browser via file->open. I get cross origin errors on my !text "template" files like this:

```
file:///Users/thegreyspot/' . clipped . '/videoIframeTemplate.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

This only applies to the files I loaded with the "!text" designation. For example, the "videoThumpTemplate.html" here:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'templates/videoThumbTemplate.html'
],function($,_,Backbone, videoThumbTemplate){
...
```

Do I HAVE to serve from a local server? Or can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is a known [chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787), the only way to make chrome load local Ajax content is to open it with the --allow-file-access-from-files flag. Star the chrome issue to keep track of changes and to motivate google to fix it.
>
> The way to make your plugins work locally is to either run the optimizer with inlineText set to true or load your page through http:// - this [gist](https://gist.github.com/JeffreyWay/1525217) contains a couple different options to start a server.
>
> I will close this issue since there is nothing we can do to fix it.  -[issues#190](https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/issues/190)

You're better of serving from a local server.. it's very easy to setup a nodejs server... or just use abode brackets, it has a live preview feature that serves stuff via node server.